# "NSURL? unable to read data" when I try getting value from String

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I'm trying to get a string to pass to an NSURL but it returns

"NSURL? unable to read data"

Here is my code:

```
let urlPath: String = "http://test.com/get.php" 
let url: NSURL =NSURL(string: urlPath)! 
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url) 
let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)! 
connection.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let urlPath: String = "http://test.com/get.php" 
let url: NSURL =NSURL(string: urlPath)!
```

this works.

### likely your real url is wrong.

Comment: So why do I get "url NSURL unable to read data " when on debug mode? is there some permissions that I should change?

Comment: just confirming... you get the error on the line `url = NSURL(...` right?

Comment: Yes, on the line url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)

Comment: Then the string is no url

Comment: Is it a local path? Because the variable is urlPath. Different constructor for a path

Comment: @Daij-Djan, Here i m getting same issue, can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that occur when running on simulators. Run a device and you should see that the `NSURL` was created properly.